# Using 2 asynchronous task in Parse Cloud query.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, parse-platform, promise

I'm very new with both Parse javascript code and Promise.

The goal of my code is to send notification to 2 players of each arena in the database and keep continue if notification send error.

```js
var query = new Parse.Query('arena');
    
    query.each((arena) => {
      return NotificationServices.sendNotification(getPlayerOne(arena))
          .then(() => {
            return NotificationServices.sendNotification(getPlayerTwo(arena))
          })
          .then(() => Parse.Promise.as(), () => Parse.Promise.as()); // Continue if notification send error.
    })
```

How can I change my code so 2 tasks sendNotification can be executed asynchronously?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "and keep continue if notification send error"? Does ChunTingLin's answer address this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want execute them async, just call them without ".then".

If you want to get a promise that these 2 finished, or one of them failed.
You can use Parse.Promise.when. [Parse.Promise.when](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_when) is near to es6 [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

try this one

```
var query = new Parse.Query('arena');

query.each((arena) => {
  var promise1 = NotificationServices.sendNotification(getPlayerOne(arena));
  var promise2 = NotificationServices.sendNotification(getPlayerTwo(arena));
  return Parse.Promise.when([promise1, promise2])
      .then(() => Parse.Promise.as(), () => Parse.Promise.as()); 
})
```